# Is "Starts out/off well" an idiomatic expression?

Tags: idioms

In the context of a greeting card, would it be idiomatic to say, "Hope [noun] starts out/off well," or is this awkward?

Comment: It looks literal to me. Why do think it might be idiomatic?

Comment: This is a journey metaphor, with motion and time synchronized. Therefore, only an event or a state with a beginning can "start off/out". We are not given any other information about what the event or state might be, so we can't say more. I wouldn't say this is "idiomatic", exactly; it follows rules, but it isn't obvious. I might add that the context of a greeting card ***IS*** an idiomatic context, and idiomatic phrases are not only common, but normal there.

Comment: To me, "starts off well" always has an implied "but then..." clause, so I would not want to see it on a greeting card. "The day dawned clear and bright..." is probably not going to end well.

Answer (score 1):

> is this awkward

Yes, I think it is. I would say it is all good, rather than just the start:

> I hope [noun] goes well

so that you aren't just saying - *"I hope only the beginning bit goes well"*, which is what it sounds like.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question as asked. That's just writing advice.

Comment: @canis edited to improve.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely fine if the beginning is important and may determine success.

> I hope that your new job starts off well.

or

> I hope that your new job gets off to a great start.

Otherwise, it sounds better to say (as Tim answered):

> I hope that the ceremony goes well.